# Where is the Editor Window in MySQL Workbench 6.0.8?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm following a tutorial to learn MySQL and I'm supposed to paste a text file into the Editor Window in Workbench to create tables, then populate them with another text file. I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.0.8 and I don't know where the Editor Window is. Haven't found a space that takes the pasted text. Could someone please tell me where the Editor Window is for starters? If you could give me some guidance to set up the tables in Workbench 6.0.8 that would be wonderful too! I've looked around online for a couple of hours to no avail. Thank you.

Comment: You need to set up a connection to a working database. The editor window appears when you open the connection.

Comment: Open a connection, then the editor will popup. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which tutorial you are following, but try [the one from MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial.html) which explains all 3 major parts of MySQL Workbench (administration, modelling, SQL work). The administration chapter shows how to create and open a connection while the last one then shows how to query tables, add data etc.

Comment: Thank you to all who responded. I'm using a purchased tutorial. I think the working database is provided through a website associated with the tutorial, and that's what I'm trying to connect with unsuccessfully so far. I'll read through the MySQL link you gave me, Mike Lischke. Thank you again.